# Need of listening incoming emails using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, exchange-server, apache-camel-mail

Looking for some ideas on how to retrieve incoming emails (Exchange Server) for processing, like retrieve some information and invoke a web service. The service should constantly listening for new emails. So far we are looking into this using Spring Boot, and Apache Camel or Sprint Integration. Cannot find a clear example on this.
Hope someone help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Spring Integration documentation about e-mail support: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/mail.html#mail.

The `MailTests` can serve as a good sample how to configure Spring Integration channel adapters for e-mail polling: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/main/spring-integration-mail/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/mail/dsl/MailTests.java.

The Spring Boot environment doesn't matter at this point: there is no any auto-configuration for mail polling, so everything should be transparent as long as as you use Spring Integration recommendations.

Unfortunately the official sample we have is still an XML, but should give you some ideas what and how should be configuration for IMAP or POP3: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/main/basic/mail

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the this API -
https://www.independentsoft.de/jwebservices/tutorial/findmessages1.html

You can create Spring scheduler to poll the exchange server to get the messages arrived in given time interval.